# Chrome Remote Desktop cannot connect to online remote device

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, chrome-remote-desktop

I have a Windows 10 computer that is located at my home and it has the Chrome Remote Desktop application installed. I can usually connect to it from my Chromebook laptop at home by accessing the remote desktop web portal at https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/

When I bring my Chromebook outside of my home to another wifi network, I can access the web portal and I see that my remote Windows 10 computer is "Online". However, if I click on it to connect, it will stay on the progress circle for about 30 seconds and then jump back to the list of "Remote devices" without any error message. I can try again many times with the same result and every time the "Remote devices" list shows my Windows 10 computer as "Online".

Is there anything I'm missing such as a recommended home router configuration or anything like that? According to google remote desktop portal I was expecting it to work as is.